# AWS Log Insights parse not working properly

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

My message looks like :

`@message     2022-06-06 12:16:31 9d6052b7-98ed-47db-b260-3ca2f718b10a INFO NodeHandler:27 - POST /node`

In the log insights query, I'm using :

```
fields @message
| parse message 'INFO * - *' as class, text
```

When I run this, although the message gets displayed, class and text are not having any value even for the message mentioned above.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Hey! No. This was solved. Thanks!